# Publish NuGet package to private GitHub registry

Tags: github, nuget, github-actions

I have a class library project that I keep in a **private** GitHub repo. I set up a GitHub action to create a NuGet package and push it to my **private** NuGet registry on GitHub.

The build process is working fine but getting stuck at NuGet push because it's unable to find the directory where the NuGet package is created. The error I get is:

> Run dotnet nuget push
> "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/bin/Release/MyLibrary.Core.1.3.1.nupkg" --source
> "github"   dotnet nuget push
> "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/bin/Release/MyLibrary.Core.1.3.1.nupkg" --source
> "github"   shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}   env:
> DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet    error: Could not find a part of the path
> '/home/runner/work/my-core-library/my-core-library/bin/Release'.

Here's the `yaml` file for this job:

```
name: Publish MyLibrary.Core NuGet to GitHub Packages

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build-pack-n-ship:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Create NuGet package
      run: dotnet pack --configuration Release
    - name: Add Package Source
      run: dotnet nuget add source --username my_github_username --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/my_company_account/index.json"
    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages
      run: dotnet nuget push "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/bin/Release/MyLibrary.Core.${{ steps.get-version.outputs.version }}.nupkg" --source "github"
```

Any idea what maybe the cause and how to fix it?

UPDATE:

I added a line to run `ls -l` as suggested in a comment. Here's what I get when that line executes:

```
ls -l
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 10 runner docker 4096 Mar 27 18:37 MyLibrary.Core
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 1114 Mar 27 18:37 MyLibrary.Core.sln
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker  269 Mar 27 18:37 README.md
```

Comment: Did you try to verify the location when the `.nupkg` was created by running `pwd` and/or `ls -l` commands?

Comment: I added a line to run `ls -l` and updated the original post with what I got. This is my first action so what maybe obvious to experienced users may not be for me. Is it the `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` that's causing the issue?

Comment: `ls` output doesn't show that `.nupkg` exists . Yes, you can omit `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` from that and use something like this `dotnet pack --configuration Release --output dist/`. Then, push with `dotnet nuget push "dist/MyLibrary.Core.${{ steps.get-version.outputs.version }}.nupkg" --source "github"`.

Comment: Now getting 1error: File does not exist (dist/MyLibrary.Core.1.3.1.nupkg)`. If we don't specify `--output/dist`, where is the package created?

Comment: Verify if package is there by running `ls dist`. According to your existing config, it should be under `bin/Release` directory.

Comment: BTW, where did you add `ls -l` previously? After which step? Should be after pack step i.e. `dotnet pack --configuration Release && ls -l`.

Comment: Working now! Just noticed something I hadn't noticed before. I had configured it so that my company name would be used as prefix for my package i.e. `MyCompany.MyLibrary.1.3.1.nuget`. In the `push` line, I was not using the company prefix. Using the `ls -l` helped me see it. Thank you for your help. I have a bounty on this question. Please post your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it. I'd like you to get the bounty. Thanks again. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome! :) Yes, these things happen. As a rule of thumb, you should always list the generated artifacts using `ls` command for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify that the generated package location and its name is according to what the `dotnet push` command expects.

As you're using the `ubuntu-latest` runner, you may use Bash shell commands such as `pwd` and `ls` to verify the location and name.

According to your configuration, the generated package should be under `./bin/Release` directory.

Apart from that, you may also specify the target directory with `dotnet pack` command like this:

```bash
dotnet pack --configuration Release --output target/
```

Now, the generated package will be under the `target` directory.